# Invalid drop item: Calculate statistics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, statistics

I have a number of rasters that I need to calculate histograms for. These are continuous rasters from 0 to 294.208 - many decimal places.  I need to be able to classify the histogram down to at least the first decimal.

But! I cannot get the calculate statistics tool to run.  It says that the file cannot be dropped, yet doesn't say why.

I have tried:
-Moving the tif raster out of the geodatabase.
-Using Int() to make it an integer raster
-Converting to a GRID raster.

Nothing works! I have no idea what the tool wants, and the help file doesn't say. Can you help?

Running ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message? What format (initially) are you trying to calculate statistics for? GRID rasters must have their statistics built (it's part of their spec) so if you can make them into GRID raster the statistics must be buildable. It sounds like you've got file geodatabase raster.. is the fGDB read-only or compressed?

Comment: The exact error message is: "One or more items was invalid and will not be added to the control".  I have tried both TIF and GRID as the input.  It is not a fGDB.

Comment: On which control? What value?

Comment: When I try to add the raster to the Calculate Statistics as the input raster, this is the message.

Comment: That is truly odd. Can the images be previewed in ArcCatalog? All valid raster types can have their statistics built (not 100% on rasters with attriubutes = RAT). Try right click on the Raster Dataset  to access properties in ArcCatalog, scroll down to the bottom and where it says statistics hit 'options' and 'calculate statistics' from there. Are these images in a read-only folder or on a CD/DVD?

Comment: Perhaps there is a just a bug that will not allow me to drop the raster - because it looks like I can compute the statistics fine from the Symbology layer.

Comment: There is also a Batch Calculate Statistics tool, provided you want to apply the same (default) parameters to all your rasters. Drag and drop from explorer or populate manually then go to lunch and it's all done when you get back.